# scrollIntoView() scroll only in div in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, js-scrollintoview

I have a container with some elements (see image below), and whenever I click on one of the elements, I would like them for the user to be in the center of the container.

[image: Container with my elements]

<sup>*My container where I would like to scroll to an element*</sup>

I am using a ref array for all the elements, and whenever I click on an element I will call the scrollIntoView() function.

```
        itemsRef.current[curVideoPos]?.scrollIntoView({
            block: "center",
            inline: "nearest",
        });
```

The scroll function work how I want it to be, but the only problem is that the entire page gets also moved(scrolled). So what do I need to do so that the scrollIntoView() function only scrolles in on container and not the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```

Comment: Hi, I used this method but it still scroll the whole page...